# Map Bounding Box NE and SW, get NW and SE

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, coordinates, core-location

I have two `CLLocationCoordinate2D` that represent a visible coordinate region/box on a map. They are the NE corner and the SW corner.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D neCoordinate = self.mapboxMapView.visibleCoordinateBounds.ne;
CLLocationCoordinate2D swCoordinate = self.mapboxMapView.visibleCoordinateBounds.sw;
```

---

**How can I mathematically convert those two coordinates to find the NW and SE coordinates/corners?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just pull out the equivalent points from each coordinate and combine them your own way?

`neCoordinate.latitude` (east) and `swCoordinate.longitude` (south) to make the SECoordinate?

`neCoordinate.longitude` (north) and `swCoordinate.latitude` (west) to make NWCoordinate?

aka:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D seCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude: neCoordinate.latitude, longitude: swCoordinate.longitude);
CLLocationCoordinate2D nwCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude: swCoordinate.latitude, longitude: neCoordinate.longitude);
```

Comment: That worked! Although in testing you have `seCoordinate` and `nwCoordinate` switched.